# Phonegap - Heights different when built on phonegap.com from local?

Tags: android, css, html, cordova

I'm miffed, there is no doubt about it, other then the obvious visible difference one reports the heights as:

```
 $('body').outerHeight();
 //1780
```

Compared with the app that is build with `phonegap run android --device` on my local Windows 8 Machine:

```
 $('body').outerHeight();
//640
```

I am using http://debug.build.phonegap.com/client/ to test my DOM with the live code.

It is using the exact same code base.

**Phonegap v3.3.30** on both compilers.

So, how is that the compilers will report or render different heights? Does maybe the phonegap app use a different web browser?

Other than pposting the app's here, I'm not sure how  I can give you more information?

Comment: I think it's more an issue with weinre (I've already seen some weird behaviours when using debug). Have you tried to disable weinre and use echo or alert to display the body height?

Comment: Well, I don't think its got anything to do with Weinre, based on the face that both apps look completely different :D and the document is reporting the heights the same as the bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst still odd that my local and the `build.phonegap.com` had different results I fixed this with:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Sepsifically:

```
 target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"
```